# Is it correct method for getting oauth_timestamp and oauth nounce?

Tags: swift, twitter-oauth

I am using this method to get timestamp and nounce in my code:

```
    var oauth_timestamp : String = String(Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970))
    var oauth_nonce : String = NSUUID().UUIDString
```

I am trying to make Authorization Header for twitter.

Comment: What makes you think that this is not the correct approach? Do you have any problems with it (like errors or returning the wrong timestamp)?

Comment: @Soana - Can u tell me how to get oath_signature ?? I will check oath_timestamp and oath_nounce after i have the value of oauth_signature........i got stuck with this

Comment: I don't know oauth. I ust know that your question does not state a problem or question, which makes it a pretty bad question. You should edit it to state your problem or question. Then you will probably get an answer.

Comment: Yes....i will take care of it in future :) thanku :)

Comment: You can already do this now. There is an edit link below your post (below the tags in light gray)

Comment: Did you get your solution?